# How to upload thumbnail image for ios rss feed table cell from xml feed

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, rss, uitableview

Almost finished with an rss app that I need to create for work. I am still fairly new to xcode and I have tried many different open source code's available out there. I finally found one that is more suited for my needs but the last thing I need is to get the thumbnail images to work for the table view cells. The articles title and description in the cells load up fine, but when I tried to re-write the code for the image it comes up blank.

The project was made to work with google news rss : https://news.google.com/?output=rss. The rss I am using is : http://www3.westchestergov.com/home/all-press-releases?format=feed&type=rss

Now, the part of the code I believe deals with the image downloading for the table view cells is :

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    let newsItem = RSSdataList[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView?.image != nil
    cell.textLabel?.text = newsItem.title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = newsItem.summary

    // Use cached image or download new image for the cell
    if let imgURLString = newsItem.imgURL, let cachedImage = imagesCache[imgURLString] {
        cell.imageView?.image = cachedImage

    } else if let imgURLString = newsItem.imgURL {

        // Need to set a blank image to the imageView to show the downloaded image
        let blank = UIImage(named: "Blank.jpg")
        var tempImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(blank?.CGImage!, CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80))
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(CGImage: tempImage)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)) {
            var downloadedImg = UIImage()

            if let imgURL = NSURL(string: imgURLString), let imgData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL), let img = UIImage(data: imgData) {
                downloadedImg = img
            } else {
                println("Error while downloading img")
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                if let cellToUpdate = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                    cellToUpdate.imageView?.image = downloadedImg
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

For the google rss this works fine, and when I searched through the code for thier rss i see that thier images are stored as :

```
img src=&quot;//t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSHnlu8OJiZBnM5ggUNjTe5ZwBwYWEN_xVjwglmYgUDZOdJSAc5s62-gAgTXTTu4sI8bVRc6W1k&quot; alt=&quot;&quot;
```

For the rss I am using the images are stored as :

```
<img style="border: 1px solid #cccccc; margin-bottom: 2px; margin-left: 10px; float: right;" src="http://www3.westchestergov.com/images/stories/newsPrimary2015/ferc-logo.jpg" alt="ferc-logo" width="333" height="222"
```

Can anyone shed some light on how i would be able to change the code around so that it can work with the rss feed I am using? This is the last piece of the puzzle for me and if i can get this to work i can finally put this app behind me.

Also, if it helps, there is this piece of code in my NewsItem.swift class that deals with images too:

```
    private func updateDescriptionHTMLImgURL() {
    descriptionHTML = descriptionHTML.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<img style=", withString: "src=http://")
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

the following snippet will extract any url from a string using regex.

```
var str = // your rss image string
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(http://)(.*?)(?=\")", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.allZeros, error: nil)

var urlString = ""
if let result = regex?.firstMatchInString(str, options: .allZeros, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(str))) {
    urlString = (str as NSString).substringWithRange(result.range)
}

println(urlString) // will print: http://www3.westchestergov.com/images/stories/newsPrimary2015/ferc-logo.jpg
```

edit: how to implement

I would recommend creating a function to do the conversion. Like this:

```
func convertRSSImageToURL(rssImage: String) -> NSURL? {
    let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(http://)(.*?)(?=\")", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.allZeros, error: nil)

    if let result = regex?.firstMatchInString(rssImage, options: .allZeros, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(rssImage))) {
        return NSURL(string: (rssImage as NSString).substringWithRange(result.range))
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

then you could easily add it to your code, like so:

change the line

```
} else if let imgURLString = newsItem.imgURL {
```

to

```
} else if let imgURL = convertRSSImageToURL(newsItem.imgURL) {
```

and then just delete the row:

```
let imgURL = NSURL(string: imgURLString),
```

since you already have a unwrapped `NSURL`.

side note: this is not tested, but it should give you enough to implement it on your own

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried implementing that into the code that I have above and i got a few erorrs, maybe im placing it wrong. Do i start it where "var downloadedImg = UIImage()" is in my code and edit it from there? Apologies for the newbish question but I really am new to this, trying to learn. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how you can implement it

Comment: Thanks, i've implemented it in and there were no errors during that but when i ran it I got an error at the line " } else if let imgURL = convertRSSImageToURL(newsItem.imgURL) { " i get the issue "Value of type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use "!" or '?'?" I tried using both suggestions of the ! and ? at the end of newsItem.imgURL and then it comes up with a Thread issue "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION"